# Set inactive state individually for multiple buttons <React.js>

Tags: reactjs, button, state

I am having some difficulty in setting an active/inactive state individually for multiple buttons. The code works except for that it sets the state on all buttons - not just the single intended button. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you. Function: {handleClickLock} and the button:{ this.handleClickLock(player)}>Lock}

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import bomb from './bomb.svg';
import crosshair from './crosshair.svg';
import gun from './gun.svg';
import kirpan from './kirpan.svg';
import shield from './shield.svg';
import bomb2 from './bomb2.svg';
import crosshair2 from './crosshair2.svg';
import gun2 from './gun2.svg';
import kirpan2 from './kirpan2.svg';
import shield2 from './shield2.svg';
import kick from './kick.svg';
import add from './add.svg';
import videoURL from './videoplayback.mp4';

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    let availableTeam = [<img src={bomb} alt="bomb"></img>, <img src={crosshair} alt="crosshair"></img>, <img src={gun} alt="gun"></img>, <img src={kirpan} alt="kirpan"></img>, <img src={shield} alt="shield"></img>, <img src={bomb2} alt="bomb2"></img>, <img src={crosshair2} alt="crosshair2"></img>, <img src={gun2} alt="gun2"></img>, <img src={kirpan2} alt="kirpan2"></img>, <img src={shield2} alt="shield2"></img>];
    let alphaTeam = [];
    let omegaTeam = [];
    let benchTeam = [];
    let omegaBenchTeam = [];
    this.state = {
     availableTeam : availableTeam,
     alphaTeam : [],
     omegaTeam : [],
     benchTeam : [],
     omegaBenchTeam : [],
     disabled : false
    }
    this.handleClickLock = this.handleClickLock.bind(this);
  }

  handleClickLock(player, key){
    let disabled = this.state.disabled;
    let availableTeam = this.state.availableTeam;
    if(disabled){
      this.setState({
        disabled : false,
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        disabled : true,
      });
    }
  }

  handleClickAlphaTeam(){
    let newAlphaTeam = this.state.alphaTeam;
    let availableTeam = this.state.availableTeam;
    let alphaTeam = this.state.alphaTeam;
    if(availableTeam.length >= 5){
      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        const playerIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableTeam.length);
        alphaTeam.push(availableTeam[playerIndex]);
        availableTeam.splice(playerIndex, 1);
      }
    }
    this.setState({
      alphaTeam : newAlphaTeam
    });
  };

  handleClickOmegaTeam(){
    let availableTeam = this.state.availableTeam;
    let newOmegaTeam = this.state.omegaTeam;
    let omegaTeam = this.state.omegaTeam;
    if(availableTeam.length >= 5){
      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        const playerIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableTeam.length);
        omegaTeam.push(availableTeam[playerIndex]);
        availableTeam.splice(playerIndex, 1);
      }
    }
    this.setState({
      omegaTeam : newOmegaTeam,
    });
  };

  handleClickToAlpha(player) {
    let newAlphaTeam = this.state.alphaTeam;
    let availableTeam = this.state.availableTeam;
    // if player is not in array , add him
    if(newAlphaTeam.indexOf(player)<0){
        newAlphaTeam.push(player);
        availableTeam.splice(availableTeam.indexOf(player), 1);
    }
    // if player is in the array , remove him
    else{
      newAlphaTeam.splice(newAlphaTeam.indexOf(player), 1);
    }
    //setState to rerender the App component
    this.setState({
      alphaTeam : newAlphaTeam,
    });
  }

  handleClickToOmega(player) {
    let newOmegaTeam = this.state.omegaTeam;
    let availableTeam = this.state.availableTeam;
    // if player is not in array , add him
    if(newOmegaTeam.indexOf(player)<0){
        newOmegaTeam.push(player);
        availableTeam.splice(availableTeam.indexOf(player), 1);
    }
    // if player is in the array , remove him
    else{
      newOmegaTeam.splice(newOmegaTeam.indexOf(player), 1);
    }
    //setState to rerender the App component
    this.setState({
      OmegaTeam : newOmegaTeam,
    });
  }

  handleClickAvailableAlpha(player) {
    let newAlphaTeam = this.state.alphaTeam;
    let newAvailableTeam = this.state.availableTeam;
    // if player is not in array , add him
    if(newAvailableTeam.indexOf(player)<0){
        newAvailableTeam.push(player);
        newAlphaTeam.splice(newAlphaTeam.indexOf(player), 1);
    }
    // if player is in the array , remove him
    else{
      newAvailableTeam.splice(newAvailableTeam.indexOf(player), 1);
    }
    //setState to rerender the App component
    this.setState({
      alphaTeam : newAlphaTeam,
    });
  }

  handleClickAvailableOmega(player) {
    let newOmegaTeam = this.state.omegaTeam;
    let newAvailableTeam = this.state.availableTeam;
    // if player is not in array , add him
    if(newAvailableTeam.indexOf(player)<0){
        newAvailableTeam.push(player);
        newOmegaTeam.splice(newOmegaTeam.indexOf(player), 1);
    }
    // if player is in the array , remove him
    else{
      newAvailableTeam.splice(newAvailableTeam.indexOf(player), 1);
    }
    //setState to rerender the App component
    this.setState({
      omegaTeam : newOmegaTeam,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <h1>Airsoft Championships Selection</h1>

        <div className="stayLeft">
          <div className="AvailableTeamDiv">
            <h3>Available Team Members</h3><br/>
            <button onClick={() => this.handleClickAlphaTeam()}>Generate Alpha Team</button>
            <button onClick={() => this.handleClickOmegaTeam()}>Generate Omega Team</button>
            {this.state.availableTeam.map((player, key) => <div key={key}><button>{player}</button><button disabled={this.state.disabled} className="goldBtn" onClick={() => this.handleClickToAlpha(player)}>Alpha</button><button disabled={this.state.disabled} className="redBtn" onClick={() => this.handleClickToOmega(player)}>Omega</button><button className="lockBtn" onClick={() => this.handleClickLock(player)}>Lock</button></div>)}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="stayMid">
          <div className="AlphaTeamMembers">
            <h3 className="AlphaH3">Alpha Team Members</h3>
            {this.state.alphaTeam.map((player, key) => <div key={key}><button className="AlphaTeamBtn">{player}</button><button className="kickBtn" onClick={() => this.handleClickAvailableAlpha(player)}><img src={kick} alt="kick"></img></button></div>)}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="stayRight">
          <div className="OmegaTeamMembers">
            <h3 className="OmegaH3">Omega Team Members</h3>
            {this.state.omegaTeam.map((player, key) => <div key={key}><button className="OmegaTeamBtn">{player}</button><button className="kickBtn" onClick={() => this.handleClickAvailableOmega(player)}><img src={kick} alt="kick"></img></button></div>)}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Which button you want to disable ? 'lockBtn' or 'goldBtn' or 'redBtn'

Comment: The lockBtn should inable/disable both the red and gold buttons @Dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can save `key` in the state and use it to enable/disable buttons by doing appropriate state management.

Please have a look at the demo below:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      availableTeam: [{name:"A",isLocked:false},
                      {name:"A",isLocked:false},
                      {name:"A",isLocked:false}]
    }
  }
  
  handleClickLock = (key) => {
    let teamToUpdate = this.state.availableTeam;
    this.setState({
      availableTeam: teamToUpdate.map((player, id)=>{
        if(id === key){
          return Object.assign({}, player, {
            isLocked: true
          })
        } else {
          return player;
        }
      })
    })
  }
  
  handleClickUnlock = (key) => {
    let teamToUpdate = this.state.availableTeam;
    this.setState({
      availableTeam: teamToUpdate.map((player, id)=>{
        if(id === key){
          return Object.assign({}, player, {
            isLocked: false
          })
        } else {
          return player;
        }
      })
    })
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="stayLeft">
          <div className="AvailableTeamDiv">
            <h3>Available Team Members</h3>
             {
                this.state.availableTeam.map((player, key) => {
                  return <div key={key}>
                          <button>{player.name}</button>
                          <button disabled={player.isLocked}>Alpha</button>
                          <button disabled={player.isLocked}>Omega</button>
                          <button className="lockBtn" onClick={() => this.handleClickLock(key)}>Lock</button>
                          <button className="lockBtn" onClick={() => this.handleClickUnlock(key)}>Unlock</button>
                        </div>
                })
             }
          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much @Dev !

Comment: Hey dev, the only problem I have is that the button doesn't keep its state when another is clicked. (It doesn't allow for multiple buttons to have the inactive state).Any ideas? Thanks again

Comment: @RuanPetersen, I have updated the demo. For these, you have to modify your data structure. Pl have a look at the updated code.

Comment: Genius. Thank you very much for all your help and time!

Comment: Hey @Dev , I was just wondering if I could use the handleClickLock function to remove the player from the random selection function of handleClickAlphaTeam and handleClickOmegaTeam, but at the same time still display it in the availableTeam array with the others. I have tried a few things but to no avail. I was thinking of moving the player that was Locked with the function handleClickLock to another array - would this work within the handleClickLock function? Thank you!